# mysql fetch data by mutiple fields

Tags: php, mysql

I want to do search option according to the user given inputs and and matching record with given criteria should be display.below is my code.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['search'])){
        echo "<script> document.getElementById('tblsearch').style.display = 'block' </script> "; 

        $serviceNumber='52805';

        $pendingfrom=$_POST['pendingfrom'];
        $status=$_POST['status'];
        $datefrom=$_POST['datefrom'];
        $dateto=$_POST['dateto'];
        $searchkey='serviceNumber';

        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM user WHERE ';
        $where = array();
        $values = array();
        $types = '';

        if (!empty($_POST['name'])) {
            $where[] = 'Username = ?';
            $values[] = $_POST['name'];
            $types .= 's';
        }

        if (!empty($_POST['status'])) {
            $where[] = 'status = ?';
            $values[] = $_POST['status'];
            $types .= 's';
        }

        $sql .= implode(' AND ',$where);

        $sth = $dbcon->prepare($sql);
        $sth->bind_param('ss',$name,$status);
        $sth->execute();
        $result=$sth->store_result();

        ?>
            <tr>

            <td><?php echo  ?></td>

                <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" name="view" id="view" value="<?php echo $row['rid'] ?>">View</button></td>
                </form>
            </tr>
        <?php
    }
?>
```

So i need to fetch record details column by column and set it to a table.
I have store the result to the $result variable.
After that to get data column by column wht do I need to do.
If any one can help it is appreciated.

Comment: what's wrong with your current code?

Comment: i want to get the result row data column by column